# How to combine dynamic and static routes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to combine dynamic and static routing in React. In my website i need to display bunch of products and they are displayed by using a dynamic routing `<Route path={"/:products"}/>` but every single product has his own 'Install' page but by running `<Route path ={"/:products/install"}>Install</Route>` it doesn't work.
In the product page i use link to go to /install route: `<Link to="/SF43/install">SF34 install page</Link>`
How can i solve it?

Comment: Have you tried using `<Route exact path=...` ?

Comment: Is your dynamic route <Route path={"/:products"}/> working but <Route path ={"/:products/install"}>Install</Route> not?

Comment: Hi @ShwetaKale yes, exactly

Comment: Try it without adding {} and as Tushar said add exact too

Comment: I found the problem. My `<Route path="{/:product}/>` doesn't have an `exact` so when the route become /:product/install it continue rendering the product page instead of the installation page. While i'm at it... for good practice the best way to declare the routes is in the App.js page?

Comment: @MattiaBertoni I have explained the details for my initial comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `exact`:

```
<Route exact path="/:products"/>
<Route exact path ="/:products/install">Install</Route>
```

Answer (score 3):

Explaining my initial comment.

As stated, you are missing `exact` in your `Route`. The `exact` param comes into play when you have multiple paths that have similar names (your initial problem)

```
<Route exact path="/:products"/>
<Route exact path ="/:products/install">Install</Route>
```

**What does exact do?**

The `exact` param disables the partial matching for a route and makes sure that it only returns the route if the path is an `EXACT` match to the current url.

**Where you should define routes?**

App.js is a good starting point for main routes. If you have nested components like Parent > Child, and each chuld can be different, then define Parent in App.js and Inside Parent Component, define routes for your Child.

In general, it all depends on your app flow and Architecture

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll definitely change my routes definitions for the Child inside the Parent Component

Answer (score -1):

You could try to remove the object in your path prop

Change this

```
<Route path={"/:products"}/>
```

for

```
<Route path="/:products"/>
```

It's the only thing I saw as a problem here, I've wrote your code just to test and it works

Check it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-microservice-mqv3i?file=/src/App.js)